# Algorithm for finding minimum value of abs(A[i]+A[j]-k)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have an integer array `A` containing both positive and negative numbers. I have to find the minimum value of `abs(A[i] + A[j] - k)`, where `i != j`.

I thought of sorting the array and using the two-pointer approach (as described at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-pointers-technique/) and find the minimum. Time complexity is `O(n*log(n))`. Can this be done in `O(n)`?

Comment: What is `k` here?

Comment: Please don't describe your code, try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of to *show* us instead.

Comment: k is any given sum.

Comment: I don't think your algorithm is complete. What if I have array `[1, 2, 3, 5, 8]` and `k=4`? Then your solution should be `i=0, j=3`, but you wouldn't find it.

Comment: What is a "given sum"?

Comment: If `k` doesn't change does it even matter? Can we just find the max `abs(A[i] + A[j])` where `i != j`?

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic if there was no `abs` then I'd agree with you, but in a minimization problem, the `abs` changes everything. We're essentially looking for the sum of two values in an array that comes closest to `k`. (so `k` actually really matters here)

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-possible-value-ai-aj-k-given-array-k/

Comment: @abhishek keshri I know. I was asking whether there was an O(n) solution.

Comment: @VedantDixit yes there is- hint: `unordered_map`

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri Using an `unordered_map` you could find the **closest** value to whatever you're looking at to form a possible pair in `O(log(n))` time, but you'd still need to loop over all values in the array. Shortest time using that algorithm would be `O(nlog(n))`

Comment: Does the input source describe the range of the numbers? If so, maybe you could use bucket sort. This could reduce your time complexity from `O(nlogn)` to `O(n)`. But the drawback is more space. [Reference here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort)

Comment: @Mathers the problem isn't sorting the array. we need to traverse the whole array and then find closest value which will take minimum of O(nlogn) time as scohe said, and I provided the code with

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri The questions mentions a `O(n)` method that works on a sorted array

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic I dont think that solutio will work for this case

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri If the array can be sorted in `O(n)` the `O(n)` pair finding algorithm can then be used. The combined solution works on unsorted arrays in `O(n)` time.

Comment: @Mathers No, there is no range mentioned in the problem

Comment: this is possible using Standard Deviation where your `k` is the mean

Comment: Do you mean _O(n)_ **after** sorting (or with a linear-time sort, where that applies)?

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri using a `unordered_map` will work only if we need to find a specific 
number i.e. `abs(A[i] + A[j] - k) = x` but will not work when we have to find the minimum.

Comment: Could you please show in your question how this could be done in O(n log n)? The link you posted is for finding an exact element using pointers, not a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the *O(n)* requirement applies after any sorting (or that your problem domain supports [linear-time sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_sorting)), you can use a trivial variation on the two-pointers algorithm (even for the case with two distinct arrays, where presumably one would not require `i!=j`).  Consider the sums of the elements of two sorted arrays laid out in a rectangle:

```
    A= 4  9 17 22 29
 B= 7 11 16 24 29 36
   19 23 28 36 41 48
   20 24 29 37 42 49
   35 39 44 52 57 64
```

Suppose that *k*=40.  By checking the lower-leftmost value (which is smaller), we can immediately rule out most of a column as containing the closest value, since those values must be *even smaller*:

```
    A= 4  9 17 22 29
 B= 7    16 24 29 36
   19    28 36 41 48
   20    29 37 42 49
   35 39 44 52 57 64
```

So we next check the value to the right (which is to say we increment the pointer into `A`).  It is larger than *k*, so it eliminates the rest of that row:

```
    A= 4  9 17 22 29
 B= 7    16 24 29 36
   19    28 36 41 48
   20    29 37 42 49
   35 39 44
```

The next move must then be `--b`.  Continuing this way cuts a path through the rectangle:

```
    A= 4  9 17 22 29
 B= 7          29 36
   19          41
   20    29 37 42
   35 39 44
```

You can move either direction (or diagonally) on an exact match (or just bail early if one hit is enough).  In general, the path may exit the rectangle other than at a corner.  For the case with only one array, you can stop as soon as it hits the diagonal (*i.e.*, when `i>=j`), disregarding any last value stepped to.

This path obviously has *O(n)* entries, since at every step it moves up or right (or both).  One of them must be the closest to *k* (here, 4+35 and 22+19 are tied).

See also [X+Y sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_%2B_Y_sorting); this problem is a sort of "X+Y binary search".

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. Don't change the question to fit your own needs.  The question is pretty clear as it is.

Comment: @VedantDixit: I asked a clarifying question, but got no answer.  Since it is obviously impossible to do a linear-time algorithm including a (comparison) sort, and I’m sure (without proof) that the problem cannot be solved faster without sorting, I edited the question to phrase it in those terms _without_ excluding the possibility that someone more clever than I can solve it without sorting.  What else do you think I changed in the intent of the question?

Comment: Doesn't your action called "rule out" hide complexity you did not aggregate? What is the process of finding the range of elements to "rule out?"

Comment: In reply to @גלעדברקן: Ruling out part of the table just means you don’t explore in that direction.  There is no actual O(n^2)-sized table in memory being altered.

Comment: You still didn't answer my question, '"what is the process of finding the range of elements to "rule out" (at each iteration) and doesn't it hide additional complexity?

Comment: @גלעדברקן: The range to rule out is the partial column above a space or the partial row to the right of it.  You always step up or right (or diagonally in the special case mentioned); if you draw out the steps it’s obvious that, after “ruling out”, the current space has only one neighbor still eligible, and you move to it.  Incrementing/decrementing the pointers/indices is literally the only operation performed.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it now. Thanks!

Comment: @גלעדברקן : It’s the entire column/row beyond the current space.  (Everything in the other direction has already been visited or ruled out anyway.)